# Align bars more than 2 bars in flot

Tags: javascript, flot

I'm trying to use flot to create a graph that has multiple bars in each x axis space, I almost have this working however, I would like all of the bars to appear next to each other, but the only options to align: 'left', align: 'right' or align: 'center'. This means with more than three bars they overlap, is there anyway to plot this graph in this way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want each bar in a series to appear next to each other, you'll have to use flot's [orderBars plugin](https://github.com/emmerich/flot-orderBars).

You can specify the order of each series by including the plugin and adding an `order` property to each series `bars` property:

```
var series = [];

series.push({
    data: [],  // your raw data
    bars: {
        order: 0
    }
});

series.push({
    data: [], // your raw data
    bars: {
        order: 1
    }
});
```

You'll also want to pick an appropriate `barWidth` value depending on how many series you have. In the code snippet below, I picked a `barWidth` of `.25` for three series:

```js
$(function () {
    var data1 = [
        [0, 12.3],
        [1, 295],
        [2, 143],
        [3, 79],
        [4, 125],
        [5, 8],
        [6, 125] 
        ];
    var data2 = [
        [0, 15],
        [1, 28.95],
        [2, 163],
        [3, 74],
        [4, 125],
        [5, 85],
        [6, 125] 
        ];
    var data3 = [
        [0, 158],
        [1, 28.95],
        [2, 103],
        [3, 74],
        [4, 145],
        [5, 85],
        [6, 105] 
        ];

var dataSet = [{
        data: data1,
        bars: { order: 1 }
    },{
        data: data2,
        bars: { order: 2 }
    },{
        data: data3,
        bars: { order: 3 }
    }];

    $.plot("#chart", dataSet, {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: .25
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#chart {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/emmerich/flot-orderBars/master/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```